# When to use Single Slit Destructive Interference and Double-Slit

Tags: double-slit-experiment, huygens-principle

QUESTION:
Two 0.010-mm-wide slits are 0.030mm apart (center to center). Determine (a) the
spacing between interference fringes for 580 nm light on a screen 1.0 m away and (b)
the distance between the two diffraction minima on either side of the central
maximum of the envelope.

MY ANSWER:

a) I understand that this is a double slit experiment, we can easily find the distances between two maximas, with the following equation: $m\lambda = dsin(\theta)$, but since the screen is relatively larger compared to the distance between the two slits, we use a small angle approximation to have $sin(\theta) \approx tan(\theta) = \frac{y}{L}$ Where $y$ is the length between two maximas, and $L$ is distance between the slit and the screen.

Regarding part a), would the distances between each maxima be the same? I would assume it would because it is creating a sinusoidal wave envelope.

b) I attempted to use the following equation to solve for the dark bands (minimas) on the screen with the following equation for double-slit destructive interference: $(m+\frac{1}{2})\lambda = dsin(\theta)$ again small angle approximation for $sin(\theta)$. However, my answer is wrong compared to the answer key which it uses the equation for single-slit destructive interference: $m\lambda = wsin(\theta)$, where $w$ is the width of each slit.

Regarding part b), i find it hard to understand why they use a different equation and also why is the length from the central maxima to the first order minima larger than the length between the first order maxima and the central maxima? Shouldn't it be shorter?

This is the following link to the answer key provided: [http://www.sfu.ca/~mxchen/phys1021003/p102a08s.pdf](http://www.sfu.ca/%7Emxchen/phys1021003/p102a08s.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not for the first minima close to the 0 max, but the first maxima of the envelope the second red line points to it. so its the minimum for one of the slits. for the first min next to the central max, you are right.

Comment: I understand now, it actually refers to the envelope pattern created by a single slit (hence why they say minima and not dark fringes), the double-slit diffraction patterns all happen within the single-slit envelope but those dark spots created within the main envelope aren't technically "global minimas" but more local. Is that the right way to think about it?